# Order Item shows Number after option name

Tags: cartthrob, matrix

I have a confirmation email which shows the customer which item & option they have selected. For some reason it is also showing numbers "1 0" after the option name (Think these are pulled from the matrix field):

*Option Name 1 0*

How can I remove these numbers?

Here is the code I am using:

```
{exp:cartthrob:submitted_order_info}    
{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}"}{item_options}{option_name}{/item_options}{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
{/exp:cartthrob:submitted_order_info}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding backspace option helped remove the numbers, not sure why they show when the database entry does not have nay numbers. Strange.

```
{item_options backspace="2"}{option_name}{/item_options}
```